# Dynamically adding a styled label to an ASP.Net Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have the following code which adds a label and a gridview to an asp.net page:

```
  GridView grd = CreateGridView(kvp.Key.Text);
  Label l = new Label();
  l.Text = "some text";
  l.CssClass = "this has no effect";
  placeHolderResults.Controls.Add(l);
  placeHolderResults.Controls.Add(grd);
```

Two questions really:

1. As the page will have a multiple and unknow quantity of Label + Grid pairs I'm looping through the above code, is this the best way to add the controls to the page?
2. I cannot style the label? How do you do it? Looking at the HTML which is created, the label turns out to be a SPAN.

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Comment: where do you define your styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

l.CssClass will only have effect if you put the class name from a style into it. For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .boldText {text-weight: bold}
</style>

// then the following should work
l.CssClass = "boldText";

// this will generate: <span class="boldText">your text</span>
```

If you just want to add styling directly, then you can do the following:

```
l.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Red;font-weight:bold;");
// this will generate <span style="color:Red;font-weight:bold">your text</span>
```

I hope this helps. Have fun coding!

PS: 
`<asp:Literal>` always generates **plain text** 
`<asp:Label>` generates **`<SPAN>`** 
`<asp:Panel>` generates **`<DIV>`**

EDITED on 2010.12.09 - fixed bugs in example code based on Jim's comment

Comment: thanks for your answer. Attributes was the answer I was after - mental block. Just one thing, your code is slightly wrong and should read l.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Red;font-weight:bold;")

Answer (score 1):

Change it to RED BOLD:

```
lblMyLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");
lblMyLabel.Style["font-weight"] = "bold";
```

Change it to BLACK NORMAL:

```
lblMyLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
lblMyLabel.Style["font-weight"] = "normal";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterStyle
```

and method

```
public void Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle key, string value);
```

Sample:

```
Label label = new Label 
{ 
    Text = "some text";
    CssClass = "yourClass"
};
label.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginRight, "12px");
parentControl.Controls.Add(label);
```

Answer (score 0):

The class question is already been answered, for the "span" tag to be changed, i recommend using the object HtmlGenericControl and assigning it the property TagName to the desired tag, for example:

```
HtmlGenericControl myControl = new HmtlGenericControl { TagName = "label"};
```